# TYPO3 Flexform Cache

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, flexform

Caching problem with TYPO3 8.x Flexforms. If I change the flexform configuration I have to restart the Docker Apache web server. Is there a better way to modify Flexforms without web server restart in TYPO3?

Steps I already tried on my docker debian9 lamp stack:

1.
in setup.ts I have already all cache disabled.
config.no_cache = 1

2.
I also tried
rm -Rf typo3temp with no effect

3.
and clear all cache in install tool no effect

4.
reload frame in chrome or with shift+cmd+r no effect

6.
Added options.clearCache.system = 1 into the field User TSconfig
In TYPO3 V8 'flush system cache' it is not needed anymore I 'flush all cache' should work fine.

```xml
<!--
for example modification in custom_flexform.xml before:
-->
<elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,png,gif</elementBrowserAllowed>

<!--
for example modification in custom_flexform.xml after:
-->
<elementBrowserAllowed>jpg</elementBrowserAllowed>
```

without restart the web server, flexform I'm backend doesn't update my Flexform config.

Answer (score 3):

This might be no caching issue.

When you make changes to your flexform setting in your `custom_flexform.xml` this will have no impact on your already saved records.

To get a feeling for whats going on, have a look into the `pi_flexform` field, most likely in the `tt_content` table or your custom table.

If the value in this filed is still holding your old flexform, you can simply open and save the record to rewrite it.

There is also an CLI command that you can use to fix your flexforms, you need EXT:typo3_console for that.

- TYPO3 Composer Mode: `./vendor/bin/typo3cms cleanup:flexforms`
- TYPO3 Classic Mode: `./typo3cms cleanup:flexforms`

Then clear the frontend cache and reload your page.